# JPA-Hibernate-EJB: More than one row with the given identifier was found

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0, uniqueidentifier, one-to-one

Iam developing EJB-JPA-JSF project. But I have a problem. I get an error for this query:

```
select u from Ucretlendirme u join u.tarife_KullanimTipiServis tks join tks.kullanimTipiServis ks join ks.servis s join tks.tarife t join ks.kullanimTipi k where s.servisID=:sID and t.tarifeID=:tID and k.kullanimTipiID=:kID
```

---

```
Error:  javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.HibernateException: More than one row with the given identifier was found: 1, for class: tr.com.vodafone.optimum.entities.Period
```

---

How can I fix this error

```
@Entity
public class Period {
    ...
@ManyToOne
private PeriyodType periodType;
@OneToOne(mappedBy="period")
private Ucretlendirme ucretlendirme;
}
```

---

```
@Entity
public class PeriyodType {
....
@OneToMany(mappedBy="periodType",fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
private List<Period> periyodlar;
}
```

---

```
@Entity
public class Ucretlendirme {
...
@OneToOne
private Period period;
@OneToOne(mappedBy="ucretlendirme")
private Tarife_KullanimTipiServis tarife_KullanimTipiServis;
}
```

---

```
@Entity
public class Tarife_KullanimTipiServis {
    ....
@ManyToOne
private Tarife tarife;
@ManyToOne 
private KullanimTipi_Servis kullanimTipiServis;
@OneToOne
private Ucretlendirme ucretlendirme;
}
```

---

```
@Entity
public class Tarife {
@OneToMany(mappedBy="tarife",fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
private List<Tarife_KullanimTipiServis> tarife_kullanimtipiservisler;
}
```

---

```
@Entity
public class KullanimTipi_Servis {
@ManyToOne
private KullanimTipi kullanimTipi;
@ManyToOne 
private Servis servis;
@OneToMany(mappedBy="kullanimTipiServis",fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
private List<Tarife_KullanimTipiServis> tarife_kullanimtipiservisler;
}
```

---

```
@Entity
public class Servis {
@OneToMany(mappedBy="servis",fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
private List<KullanimTipi_Servis> kullanimtipi_servisler;
}

@Entity
public class KullanimTipi {
 ....
@OneToMany(mappedBy="kullanimTipi",fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
private List<KullanimTipi_Servis> kullanimtipi_servisler;
}
```

Comment: Your HQL query must be returning duplicated entities with the same id.
Try to enable SQL logging and execute the select by hand and see what it returns.

Comment: thank you, I solve this problem. I missed a spot. When Saving instance, ı should save Period instance each Ucretlendirme. I was wrong.

Answer (score -1):

In your database  you have a table  which have an inverse relationship data added.
for example your tables relaiontionship is many to one but your  tables data is like many to many.you must delete like this rows.

Comment: Please add details on the table and the relationship you're referring at.